# Git is tracking files (incorrectly?) between different branches

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, branching-and-merging

To start, I'm working with Git/TFS/VS Pro 2015

I frequently encounter an issue when switching between branches

For example, I'll checkout BranchA

BranchA contains various updates to File1.cs, File2.cs, File3.cs

Now I checkout BranchB

Changes made in BranchB are irrelevant at this point.

Before I can leave BranchB and checkout any other Branch, visual studio is stating I have uncommitted changes made to files File1.cs, File2.cs, File3.cs (none of these files show any differences, they are the files I viewed in BranchA, and I'm currently in BranchB where the files are untouched)

I can't "Undo Changes" because the files  are unedited. To clear these files out of staging I have to simply commit the unchanged files, which clutters up the branch.

What causes this? What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Check first as [in this issue](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/528) the value of `git config core.autocrlf`.

Make sure to set it to `false`, and re-clone your project, then try again your sequence of branches checkouts.
That would avoid any eol (end of line) characters automatic translation.